# Shorter x86 call instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, call, micro-optimization, machine-code

For context I am x86 golfing.

```
00000005 <start>:
   5:   e8 25 00 00 00          call   2f <cube>
   a:   50                      push   %eax
```

Multiple calls later...

```
0000002f <cube>:
  2f:   89 c8                   mov    %ecx,%eax
  31:   f7 e9                   imul   %ecx
  33:   f7 e9                   imul   %ecx
  35:   c3                      ret
```

`call` took 5 bytes even though the offset fit into a single byte! Is there any way to write `call cube` and assemble with GNU assembler and get a smaller offset? I understand 16 bit offsets could be used, but ideally I'd have a 2 byte instruction like `call reg`.

Comment: There is no 2-byte `call` equivalent to `jmp` in the current x86 instruction set. Alternatives (messing with the stack) would be as long or longer.

Comment: @usr2564301 could I move the address of my label into a register and use `FF` call?

Comment: For a one-time use that would not be shorter either. You cannot encode a *relative* address in `call reg`, so loading the register itself would start off with the exact same length – and then you need to call it. If this jump occurs more, it may start paying off at the 5th or 6th call or so.

Comment: Yes, if you can generate a full address in a register in less than 3 bytes...  Even a RIP-relative LEA doesn't help, because it only exists in `rel32` form, not `rel8`.  Most OSes don't let you map anything in the lowest pages (so NULL-pointer deref faults), so usable addresses are larger than 16 bits, outside of 16-bit mode.

Comment: @PeterCordes I am using this call multiple times, so maybe even if putting the address in the register takes several bytes, we save overall. Can you post as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `call rel8`, or any way to push a return address and `jmp` in fewer than 5 bytes.

To come out ahead with `call reg`, you need to generate a full address in a register in less than 3 bytes.  Even a RIP-relative LEA doesn't help, because it only exists in `rel32` form, not `rel8`.
For a single `call`, clearly not worth it.

**If you can reuse the same function pointer register for multiple 2-byte `call reg` instructions, then you come out ahead even with just 2 `call`s.** (5 byte `mov reg, imm32` plus 2x 2-byte `call reg` is a total of 9 bytes, vs. 10 for 2x 5-byte `call`).  But it does cost you a register.

---

Most OSes don't let you map anything in the lowest pages (so NULL-pointer deref faults), so usable addresses are larger than 16 bits in 32 or 64-bit mode.  `66 E8 rel16` (4 byte `callw`) isn't an option even in 32-bit mode; that would truncate EIP to IP.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call

In 32-bit / 64-bit code, I'd consider the linker options necessary to get your code mapped in the zero page as part of the byte-count of your code-golf answer.  ([And also the `/proc/sys/vm/mmap_min_addr` kernel setting](https://wiki.debian.org/mmap_min_addr), or equivalent on other OSes)  Normally we justify not counting the ELF metadata at all in code-golf, only bytes of the `.text` section, so special linker tricks opens up a can of worms there.

---

Generally avoid `call` in code-golf if you can.  It's usually better to structure your loops to avoid needing code-reuse.  e.g. `jmp` into the middle of a loop to get part of the loop to run the right number of times, instead of calling a block multiple times.

I guess I usually look at code-golf questions which lend themselves naturally to machine code, and can avoid needing the same block of code from multiple places.  I can already spend hours tweaking a short function, so starting an answer to a question that will take more code (and thus have even more room for optimization between / across parts of it) is rare for me.

Comment: I think `mov`/`lea` label into register is what I'll go for (I wouldn't use `call` for a single call). I also really like the loop idea.

Comment: @qwr: fun trick: you can skip the first 4 instruction bytes of a loop with 1 byte instead of a 2-byte `jmp`.  Use `db 0x3D`, the opcode for `cmp eax, imm32` at the top of the loop.  On loop entry, it will consume 4 bytes as an immediate.  But when you branch back to the top of the loop, that's inside the bytes that were the immediate, so they run as instructions.

Comment: I don't think I'm ready for executing immediates as code yet...! Though it probably is a technique important security-wise.

Comment: @PeterCordes An old comment, but what you describe here is what I call [skipping instructions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132981/tips-for-golfing-in-x86-x64-machine-code/235553#235553). Of course **you** are aware of that answer already but I thought it relevant here.